# Unable to acquire sound with PyAudio, but arecord works

Tags: python-3.x, embedded-linux, yocto, pyaudio, portaudio

I am working on a imx8MP board running Yocto Linux and I wrote a python script that acquires sound from a microphone using PyAudio. I checked that I can acquire using the `arecord` tool:

```
./arecord -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault:CARD=imxaudiosph0645
    imx-audio-sph0645, 
    Default Audio Device

./arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: imxaudiosph0645 [imx-audio-sph0645], device 0: imx-sph0645 snd-soc-dummy-dai-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

 # this works fine
./arecord -D hw:0,0 -r 32000 -f S32_LE -c 1 -d 5 -t wav -v 32000_32_1.wav
```

However, when using PyAudio I got the following warnings and errors:

```
>>> import pyaudio as pa
>>> p=pa.PyAudio()
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1043:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1043:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1120:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1043:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1043:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1120:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1043:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1120:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1043:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1043:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1120:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1043:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1120:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1043:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:575:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) The dsnoop plugin supports only capture stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:649:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:575:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) The dsnoop plugin supports only capture stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:575:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) The dsnoop plugin supports only capture stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:649:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:575:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) The dsnoop plugin supports only capture stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:649:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:575:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) The dsnoop plugin supports only capture stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:575:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) The dsnoop plugin supports only capture stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:649:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:575:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) The dsnoop plugin supports only capture stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:649:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:575:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) The dsnoop plugin supports only capture stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:575:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) The dsnoop plugin supports only capture stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:649:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1120:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:649:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1120:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dshare.c:698:(snd_pcm_dshare_open) The dshare plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dshare.c:698:(snd_pcm_dshare_open) The dshare plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1824:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:649:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_direct.c:1271:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib ../../../alsa-lib-1.1.9/src/pcm/pcm_dmix.c:1120:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to initialize slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock


>>> stream=p.open(format=pa.paInt16, channels=1, rate=44100, frames_per_buffer=1024, input=True)
Expression 'r' failed in '../portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2092
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_FinishConfigure( &self->capture, hwParamsCapture, inParams, self->primeBuffers, realSr, inputLatency )' failed in '../portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2725
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in '../portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2837
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error

>>> pa.pa.get_device_count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno -10000] PortAudio not initialized
```

What could be the problem?

Some useful info about the system:

python version 3.7.8

pyaudio version 0.2.11

output of `uname`:

```
Linux 5.4.70+gbc47e1c1ba40 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jul 13 06:41:31 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

output of `cat /proc/asound/version`

```
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k5.4.70+gbc47e1c1ba40.
```

output of dmesg when the script is executed:

```
[  338.294049] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.297669] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 48000, sampling bits : 16
[  338.305797] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 3072000 
[  338.310531] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.314575] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.320353] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.332823] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.336465] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 44100, sampling bits : 16
[  338.344598] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 2822400 
[  338.349342] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.353395] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.359184] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.365244] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Tx rate: 1411200
[  338.372353] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  338.384619] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.388242] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 32000, sampling bits : 16
[  338.396421] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 2048000 
[  338.401168] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.405222] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.411011] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.423056] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.426664] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 22050, sampling bits : 16
[  338.434824] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 1411200 
[  338.439612] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.443701] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.449534] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.455631] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Tx rate: 705600
[  338.462645] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  338.475327] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.478978] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 22050, sampling bits : 16
[  338.487162] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 1411200 
[  338.491948] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.496029] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.501857] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.507909] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Tx rate: 705600
[  338.514978] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  338.527790] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.531458] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 16000, sampling bits : 16
[  338.539645] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 1024000 
[  338.544422] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.548466] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.554294] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.566882] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.570500] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 11025, sampling bits : 16
[  338.578635] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 705600 
[  338.583276] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.587313] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.593094] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.599151] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Tx rate: 352800
[  338.606158] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  338.618669] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.622263] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 11025, sampling bits : 16
[  338.630398] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 705600 
[  338.635044] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.639098] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.644878] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.650929] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Tx rate: 352800
[  338.657928] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  338.670138] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.673784] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 8000, sampling bits : 16
[  338.681835] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 512000 
[  338.686479] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.690530] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.696309] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.708037] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.711669] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 48000, sampling bits : 16
[  338.719838] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 3072000 
[  338.724578] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.728631] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.734417] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.746636] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.750229] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 44100, sampling bits : 16
[  338.758375] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 2822400 
[  338.763124] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.767201] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.772987] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.779042] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Rx rate: 1411200
[  338.786122] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  338.798328] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.801923] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 32000, sampling bits : 16
[  338.810055] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 2048000 
[  338.814813] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.818867] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.824654] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.836949] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.840584] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 22050, sampling bits : 16
[  338.848718] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 1411200 
[  338.853458] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.857509] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.863298] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.869349] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Rx rate: 705600
[  338.876367] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  338.887944] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.891568] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 22050, sampling bits : 16
[  338.899701] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 1411200 
[  338.904430] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.908471] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.914247] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.920302] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Rx rate: 705600
[  338.927297] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  338.939538] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.943162] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 16000, sampling bits : 16
[  338.951288] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 1024000 
[  338.956016] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  338.960067] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  338.965847] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  338.979643] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  338.983263] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 11025, sampling bits : 16
[  338.991404] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 705600 
[  338.996048] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.000098] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.005889] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.011943] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Rx rate: 352800
[  339.018938] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  339.031057] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  339.034668] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 11025, sampling bits : 16
[  339.042799] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 705600 
[  339.047443] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.051493] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.057273] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.063321] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Rx rate: 352800
[  339.070315] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  339.082677] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  339.086269] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 8000, sampling bits : 16
[  339.095656] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 512000 
[  339.100314] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.104355] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.110129] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.122424] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  339.126017] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 44100, sampling bits : 16
[  339.134157] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 2822400 
[  339.138885] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.142924] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.148699] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.154752] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Rx rate: 1411200
[  339.161841] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  339.173828] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  339.177462] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 44100, sampling bits : 16
[  339.185607] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 2822400 
[  339.190341] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.194400] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.200186] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.206240] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Tx rate: 1411200
[  339.213328] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  339.225268] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  339.228884] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 44100, sampling bits : 16
[  339.237039] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 2822400 
[  339.241780] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.245829] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.251608] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.257665] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Rx rate: 1411200
[  339.264744] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  339.275913] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  339.279535] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 44100, sampling bits : 16
[  339.287703] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 2822400 
[  339.292447] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.296499] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.302284] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.308333] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Tx rate: 1411200
[  339.315420] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  339.327644] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  339.331262] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 8, sampling rate : 48000, sampling bits : 16
[  339.339393] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 3072000 
[  339.344121] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.348161] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.353969] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.365187] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  339.368820] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 8, sampling rate : 48000, sampling bits : 16
[  339.377031] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 3072000 
[  339.381778] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.385821] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.391608] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.413009] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  339.416634] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 48000, sampling bits : 32
[  339.424764] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 3072000 
[  339.429496] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.433550] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.439330] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.451510] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  339.455138] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 44100, sampling bits : 16
[  339.463268] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 2822400 
[  339.467995] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.472042] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.477822] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.483877] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Rx rate: 1411200
[  339.490963] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  339.503008] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  339.506633] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 2, sampling rate : 44100, sampling bits : 16
[  339.514765] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 2822400 
[  339.519499] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.523547] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.529321] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.535375] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Tx rate: 1411200
[  339.542454] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
[  339.558566] [imx_sph0645_hw_params]
[  339.562160] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: channels: 1, sampling rate : 44100, sampling bits : 16
[  339.570321] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: bclk : 2822400 
[  339.575054] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] init
[  339.579101] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_fmt done
[  339.584872] [imx_sph0645_hw_params] snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk done
[  339.590920] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: failed to derive required Rx rate: 1411200
[  339.598006] fsl-sai 30c30000.sai: ASoC: can't set 30c30000.sai hw params: -22
```

Comment: The latter part of your stacktrace is useless without knowing which versions of python, linux, alsa and PortAudio you are using. How did you install pyaudio (and it's dependencies)? During your image-build or on the live system? Does pyaudio work for playback? Is anything being saved to the system logs when your python script executes?

Comment: I added some information in the original question. Pyaudio was installed during the image build. I don't have any playback device